# MS Graph & Intune: Identify a mobile device

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

Is there a way to identify a **mobile** device from the following Graph API endpoint?

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices
```

Currently we have a mix of mobile devices and Windows PC's loaded into Intune but having looked at the `deviceManagement/managedDevices` resource using MS Graph, I cannot identify a way to filter on just mobile devices. I can see that there is an `imei` property, which is understandably set for mobile devices and I can see that it is but for items that are not mobile devices, it is set to " ". The problem I have is that I cannot filter out results based on blank values, which I understand is not supported by Microsoft on the MS Graph. So for example a query like this is not working,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=imei+ne+' '
```

I've had a look at the properties returned by the resource `deviceManagement/managedDevices` but I could not spot anything that clearly marked an item as a `mobile` device. Is there another way I can filter out the blank values or is there another property I could use instead to identify that it is a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this article](https://www.petervanderwoude.nl/post/getting-started-with-filtering-and-selecting-microsoft-intune-data-via-microsoft-graph/) and my tests filter with `ne` does not work on this specific endpoint (or it does the same as `eq`). So with this property you can only filter the values you want.

Would it be a possibility to filter the mobile devices on this endpoint based on the property `operatingSystem`?

You could filter the output with something like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices?$filter=operatingSystem eq 'Android' or operatingSystem eq 'iOS'
```

In my tenant I only have Windows devices, so I am not sure if the names in my query (Android and iOS) are the correct values.